# How to replace multiple unicode characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, unicode

I have identified a couple of unicode characters in my database by means of the following query:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name NOT LIKE '%'+CAST(name AS VARCHAR(1000))+'%'
```

...with which I get stuff like this:

```
MORRISON CPA LIMITED  E¦¬Ç¦®EŒÆŒƑÈ¨ˆÅ¸«Äº‹Å‹™Æ‰€ÆŒ‰E™Å…¬Å¸
```

Is it possible to get the collation when using a REPLACE function? Something like:

```
UPDATE table SET name = REPLACE(name,NOT LIKE '%'+CAST(name AS VARCHAR(1000))+'%','')
```

I know I can individually replace them `REPLACE(name,'Æ','')` but is there a way to replace everything that is unicode?

Edit: I don't know why but I get less rows if I use

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name != CAST(name AS VARCHAR(1000))
```

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: Yes it's an int identity(1,1)

Answer (score 1):

**NVARCHAR - VARCHAR conversions**

This topic has been discussed heavily in [a previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196570/why-does-the-varchar-datatype-allow-unicode-values) on DBA.SE

Some parts of the answers on that question:

> which characters can be stored in an 8-bit / non-Unicode encoding
>   depends on the code page, which is determined by the Collation.

&

> VARCHAR can no longer be referred to as "non-Unicode". So, starting
>   with the first public beta of SQL Server 2019 in September 2018, we
>   should refer to VARCHAR as an "8-bit datatype", even when speaking in
>   terms of versions prior to SQL Server 2019. This terminology holds
>   true for all 4 types of encodings that can be used with VARCHAR:
>
> Extended ASCII Double-Byte Character Sets (DBCS) EBCDIC UTF-8
>   (Unicode)

[Solomon Rutzky](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/30859/solomon-rutzky)

> From the comments, I agree "Extended ASCII" is really bad term that
>   actually means a code page that maps characters/code points in the
>   128-255 range, beyond the standard 0-127 code point range defined by
>   ASCII.

[Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman)

Depending on your collation, some characters will be able to be stored in varchar / 8-bit datatype fields, some not.

---

> My values do not transform to '?' when casting to varchar, your fiddle
>   uses sql 2017 could that be the reason?

**This can depend on collation, and should be due to converting of certain characters**

I am using `SQL Server 2017`, collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

On my test, the `Ƒ` character was changed to  `ƒ` instead of put as `?` when converting nvarchar --> varchar.

Other than that, there are no different characters when comparing both, on my collation / version.

An example:

```
SELECT CAST([name] AS VARCHAR(1000)), [name] 
FROM dbo.Bla 
WHERE [name]
NOT LIKE '%'+CAST([name] AS VARCHAR(1000))+'%';
```

With the small difference on the F's.

```
(No column name)    name
ORRISON CPA LIMITED  E¦¬Ç¦®EŒÆŒƒÈ¨ˆÅ¸«Äº‹Å‹™Æ‰€ÆŒ‰E™Å…¬Å¸   ORRISON CPA LIMITED  E¦¬Ç¦®EŒÆŒƑÈ¨ˆÅ¸«Äº‹Å‹™Æ‰€ÆŒ‰E™Å…¬Å¸
```

You could compare the text [here](https://text-compare.com/)

Which makes the solution below not useful for you.

---

### Some workarounds on values that fail to convert would be to

1. Cast the values as `varchar(1000)`, and then remove the `?` *after validating that no `?`'s exist*.
2. Only update name values that do not have regular `?`'s.
3. Replacing the `?` to a value that cannot exist in your data and then
   replacing it back.

---

*On the premise that the unicode is changed to a ? when casting them to varchar*

**#1 Cast the values as `varchar(1000)`, and then remove the `?`.**

```
SELECT [name] FROM [dbo].[Table]    WHERE [name] like '%?%';
```

Update if none found

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[Table] SET [name] = REPLACE(CAST([name] AS VARCHAR(1000)),'?','');
```

---

**#2 Only update name values that do not have regular `?`'s.**

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table]  
SET [name] = REPLACE(CAST([name] AS VARCHAR(1000)),'?','')
WHERE [name] NOT LIKE '%?%';
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e73d510bd400b430379019511c1cedb1)

---

**#3 Replacing the `?` to a value that cannot exist in your data and then
    replacing it back.**

*With you guessed it, another `REPLACE`.*

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table] 
SET [name] = REPLACE(REPLACE(CAST(REPLACE([name],'?','THISVALUECANNOTOCCURINMYDATA') AS VARCHAR(1000)),'?',''),'THISVALUECANNOTOCCURINMYDATA','?')
```

*ReplaceCeption.*

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5d84e14b9f31b41a52b6a57ee354d722)

---

If there are no other, more foolproof, *get all unicode values and replace these* workarounds. I would use `#3` just to be sure that no original `?`s are replaced.

---

Comment: My values do not transform to '?' when casting to varchar, your fiddle uses sql 2017 could that be the reason?

Comment: @RobertoTorres You are right, the convert will change one character, making the comparison return that column.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the elaborated answer, I think I will just go full Todd Howard and tell them the database 'it just works'